# Como listar diretorio em um listview?

Tags: android, arquivo

Preciso listar um diretorio especifico do sdcard, em um listview personalizado.
Vejam como trabalho, a lista contem um botao e um titulo:

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Lista> itens;

    public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<Lista> itens) {
        //Itens que preencheram o listview
        this.itens = itens;
        //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    /**
     * Retorna a quantidade de itens
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return itens.size();
    }

    /**
     * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public Lista getItem(int position) {
        return itens.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Sem implementação
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Pega o item de acordo com a posção.
        Lista item = itens.get(position);
        //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

        //atravez do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
        //ao item e definimos as informações.
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Texto");
        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview)).setText("meu botão");
      //  ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo)).setText(item.getSubtitulo());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public void criarLista() {

    itens = new ArrayList<Lista>();

    String[] categorias = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos);

    String[] drawableCategorias = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.botao_imagem);

    for (int i = 0; i < categorias.length; ++i) {
        itens.add(new Lista(categorias[i], getResources().getIdentifier(
                drawableCategorias[i], "drawable", this.getPackageName())));
    }


    adapter = new AdapterListView(DownloadView.this, itens);        // Cria o adapter adapter = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter); // Cor quando a lista é
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
```

Achei um método para listar:

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
   theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
}
```

não sei se é a forma correta, mas como aplicar no meu listview? no meu listvire esta carregando manualmente alguns itens la do string.xml, quero listar os arquivos do diretorio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Isto é o mínimo para se obter uma lista de um diretório:**

```
    private File file;
    private List<String> minhaLista;

    minhaLista = new ArrayList<String>();   

    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File( root_sd + "/pasta" ) ;       
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
            minhaLista.add( list[i].getName() );
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, minhaLista));
```

Quer algo mais **completo**? Leia isto:

https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/02/android-listview-tutorial.html

Comment: Mas eu tenho List<Lista>        uma classe Lista , que criei com dois objetos, e um construtor.quando altero para List<Lista> minhaLista; da erro no metodo add, manda colocar o addAll, como faço no meu contexto?

Comment: Você tem CERTEZA QUE POSSUI um código que criar este caminho: `file = new File( root_sd + "/pasta" );`  SE NÃO HOUVER ESSE CAMINHO, NÃO IRÁ LISTAR NADA!

Comment: eu alterei meu adapter tudo pra string, pra adaptar no seu codigo, sim ja tenho um diretorio com o nome freedom, e alguns arquivos la na pasta, porem nao lista nada

Comment: Se a pasta freedom, estiver no SDCARD, deverá está assim: `file = new File( root_sd + "/freedom" );`...Mas qual o seu objetivo em listar ÂRQUIVOS de um diretório?

Comment: Deu certo!! na minha aplicação tenho um pequeno gerenciador de arquivos. Valeu

Comment: `FANTASTIC!!!!`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20581/discussion-between-war-lock-and-lollipop).